# How to test for method within a method in a JUnit test case?

Tags: java, testing, case

These are the methods I'm trying to test right now.

```
public void addGrade(String newGrade) {
    if (numGrades >= grades.length) {
         increaseGradesCapacity();
    }
      grades[numGrades] = newGrade;
      numGrades++;
}

public void increaseGradesCapacity() {
  String[] newGrades = new String[grades.length + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
     newGrades[i] = grades[i];
  }
  grades = newGrades;
}
```

Currently, I have one test case that tests without having to call the increaseGradesCapacity() method:

```
@Test public void addGradeTest() {
  String[] myGrades1 = {"a90", "a100", "q90", "q80", 
     "p100", "e87.5"};

  String[] myGrades2 = {"a90", "a100", "q90", "q80", 
     "p100", "e87.5", "q100"};              

  WeightedGrades2 wg = new WeightedGrades2("Aegon Targaryen", 6, myGrades1);

  wg.addGrade("q100");

  Assert.assertArrayEquals("Test for addGrade.",
     myGrades2, wg.getGrades());                           
}
```

But I'm trying to figure out how to create a test case that calls the increaseGradesCapacity() method. This is what I have right now, but it still does not satisfy the Web-CAT requirements. Anyone have any ideas?

```
@Test public void addGradeTest2() {
  String[] myGrades1 = {"a90", "a100", "q90", "q80", 
     "p100", "e87.5"};

  String[] myGrades2 = {"a90", "a100", "q90", "q80", 
     "p100", "e87.5", null, "q100"};   

  WeightedGrades2 wg = new WeightedGrades2("Anakin Skywalker", 7, myGrades1);

  wg.increaseGradesCapacity();
  wg.addGrade("q100");              

  Assert.assertArrayEquals("Test for addGrade.",
     myGrades2, wg.getGrades());
}
```

Comment: Design query: should `increaseGradesCapacity` be public? It seems like internal API. But either way, calling `addGrade` pollutes the test of increasing capacity...why not just call increaseGradesCapacity and test the array is one bigger and has correctly maintained the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what the "Web-CAT Requirement" that must be satisfied in this case, but I'll give you a general answer that hopefully answers your question.

Given that the method in question, `increaseGradesCapacity()`, is responsible for increasing the size of the `grades` array, I would simply test the size before and after the invocation of this method. So your test might look like this:

```
@Test public void addGradeTest2() {
  String[] myGrades1 = {"a90", "a100", "q90", "q80", "p100", "e87.5"};
  WeightedGrades2 wg = new WeightedGrades2("Anakin Skywalker", 7, myGrades1);

  int sizeBeforeIncrease = wg.getGrades().length;

  wg.increaseGradesCapacity();

  int sizeAfterIncrease = wg.getGrades().length;

  Assert.assertTrue("Expecting size after increase to be larger.", 
                       sizeAfterIncrease > sizeBeforeIncrease);
}
```

Notice how I ditched the `wg.addGrade('q100');` line. If your second test is solely responsible for testing the `increaseGradesCapacity()`, and the `addGrade` method modifies the grades array, whose size you ultimately want to check, then it makes the inaccurate, or at least, not focused and contained to one concept.